# How do I query for the state of a session variable in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I see that in PL/SQL it is possible to set the session state of a particular variable for the remainder of the session's lifetime.  For instance:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=<schema>
```

How do I query for the current state of this schema so I can revert back to it after performing some other statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT( 'USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA' ) FROM dual;
```